# Exclude user id completely in mysql result if active = 1 found in table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am using mysql in php to email customers a reminder email based upon certain conditions , it should only return result and email customer if that unique customer has ca account that is active=0    some customers have more than one ca account so it will both me active=0 and active=1 for their membership

I have tried the SQL below which returns 3 results 
Billy & Daniel are correct, they just have active = 0 so should appear
Becky has both active = 0 and active = 1 for her 2 respective ca accounts so the SQL should look at her query and realise "no Becky has active = 1" so should not appear.  this only Billy , Daniel are returned.

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.forename,
    u.surname,
    u.email,
    m.password,
    m.user_id,
    m.active, 
    m.promotional_code 
FROM 
    user u 
    LEFT JOIN ca_accounts c ON u.id = c.user_id 
    LEFT JOIN member m ON u.id = m.user_id 
WHERE 
    u.active = 1 AND m.active = 1 
    AND m.group_id IN (26) 
    AND (from_unixtime(m.end_date) > NOW() 
    AND from_unixtime(m.end_date) < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))  
    AND c.active = 0 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Yields :

```
id    forename surname  email   password    user_id active         
2923    Billy           billy@  NULL         2923   1   
4763    Daniel          daniel@ NULL         4763   1   
781     Beckly          becky@  NULL          781   1
```

What it should Yield :

```
id    forename surname  email   password    user_id active         
2923    Billy           billy@  NULL         2923   1   
4763    Daniel          daniel@ NULL         4763   1
```

[image of user id 781 ca account table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Qck.png)

Comment: Your question is being downvoted. Please update your post with your table structures, sample data and expected results, it will help the community to provide you with an accurate answer.

Comment: Hey @Daniel and welcome. Please provide information about your table-structure and so, as pointed out by GMB

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you provided it looks like the issue comes from table `ca_accounts`, where multiple rows belong to the same user with different values for `active` (`0` and `1`).

To solve this, you may transform the `JOIN` on `ca_accounts` into a `NOT EXISTS` ondition in the `WHERE` clause, with a correlated subquery that ensures that there is no `ca_accounts` record with `active = 1` for the given user.

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.forename,
    u.surname,
    u.email,
    m.password,
    m.user_id,
    m.active, 
    m.promotional_code 
FROM 
    user u 
    LEFT JOIN member m ON u.id = m.user_id 
WHERE 
    u.active = 1 AND m.active = 1 
    AND m.group_id IN (26) 
    AND (from_unixtime(m.end_date) > NOW() 
    AND from_unixtime(m.end_date) < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))      
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ca_accounts c 
        WHERE u.id = c.user_id AND c.active = 1
    )
LIMIT 0, 25
```